# Copy html content to clipboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, copy

I want to copy HTML content to the clipboard.

For example

[image: 1]

Answer (score 12):

In modern browsers (assuming you are working in the browser), you now have access to [navigator.clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard) api to access the clipboard.

To copy html you just need to specify a MIME type of `text/html`

However, you can also specify multiple MIME types simultaneously (which is likely what you want so as to allow the clipboard to fallback to plain text when html isn't supported).

Something like this:

```
navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({
  'text/plain': new Blob([element.innerText], {type: 'text/plain'}),
  'text/html': new Blob([element.innerHTML], {type: 'text/html'})
})])
```

Comment: I assume you meant to use innerHTML in the second type?

Comment: Thank you! I think I need to call it a night :P

Comment: Sounds like it, as you also wrote Html instead of HTML now (the property is called innerHTML). I fixed it for you, have a good night :)

Comment: A good solution with an important caveat: the ClipboardItem API is disabled behind a feature flag on Firefox by default.

Comment: Addendum to the above, looks like it may be available in Firefox in the near future. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1809106

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
import sanitizeHtml from "sanitize-html";      
const copyToClipBoard =(str)=> {
                let data= sanitizeHtml(str,{allowedTags: [ ],allowedAttributes: {},allowedIframeHostnames: []})
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(data);
        }
```

[sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html)